# Laravel form request rules with 'required' don't continue to validate further rules

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 7.11.0, I have a form request in which I am using built-in validation rules. Here is one of them

```
'title' => 'required|alpha'
```

But the problem is that if the field is empty it does not checks the rules after 'required'.[image: when required is given at the start]

Now, if I use the following code by putting alpha at the start you can see it validates both, and that what I am confused with require. I wanna know why it doesn't validate further rules when required rule validation is failed.

```
'title' => 'alpha|required'
```

This arrangement returns the following output and that's what I want...
[image: when alpha is at the start]

Comment: I think that is expected behaviour - why would you show all validation errors if you could not validate something (e.g. a date must be in future) but if nothing is added you cannot validate this.

Comment: did you tried putting number? i think it will give you the proper validation

Answer (score 1):

Found the Answer here on Github https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15084